# How to locate IP (IPv4s) by Zone - Search by Country/City

Tags: geolocation, location, ip, ipv4

Online you can find many services (sites) that allow you to trace the location of a specific IPv4 address.

But **there is a way to perform an IP search using an area (City/State/Zip Code etc.) as the search method**?

Something that allows you to search for IPs starting from a map.

If the databases are cataloged based on the location of the ISP it should be very simple to also perform the reverse search.

If anyone knows if there are specific sites/apps/mobile's apps(Android/iOS) that allow this, could you please point them out? Thanks.